# Counting values of select inputs in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble figuring out/conceptualizing how to create a component in ReactJS. I threw together a little example where I have a top component of a meal plan, then I have another component which gets used for each meal in the plan.

Now, I want a component that displays the count of the number of times a user has selected a meal category. I've whipped up a little example here. [Meal Plan Example](http://jsbin.com/vuxuze/edit?js,output)

So using the example, I want a component that summarizes how many fruits and vegetables the user has currently selected. My old way of thinking was that I would need to change a count somewhere on a category change, but I think in react this should be different and easier right? It feels like maybe I should just be (somehow?) grabbing the values of the category select boxes and counting them and rendering that out in the new component. It feels like maybe I should be looking at the ref docs, but they use a pretty simple example.

Not really sure what the right way to go about this is.

Here's the code as well.

**JSON**

```
var plan = { 
    "meals": [
      {
        "selectedFood":"",
        "mealName":"breakfast"
      },
      {
        "selectedFood":"",
        "mealName":"lunch"
      },
      {      
        "selectedFood":"",
        "mealName":"dinner"
      },
    ],
    "planOptions": [
      {
        "id":1,
        "category":"fruit",
        "food":"apple"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "category":"fruit",
        "food":"pear"
      },
      {
        "id":3,
        "category":"vegetable",
        "food":"carrot"
      },
      {
        "id":4,
        "category":"vegetable",
        "food":"corn"
      }
    ]
};
```

**JSX**

```
var PlanEntryBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            plan: {}
        };
    },
    render: function() {
    var planOpts = this.props.plan.planOptions;
    var meals = this.props.plan.meals.map(function(meal) {
            return (
                <MealEntryBox mealEntry={meal} planOptions={planOpts} />
            );
        });
        return (
        <div>
            <h1>Meals</h1>
                <table className="table">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Meal</th>
               <th>Category</th>
               <th>Food</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             {meals}
           </tbody>
         </table>
         <CategoryCounter />
       </div>
        );
    }
});

var MealEntryBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            selectedCategory: null
        };
    },
    categoryChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({selectedCategory: event.target.value});
    },
    render: function() {
        var options = _.uniq(_.pluck(this.props.planOptions, 'category'));
        var categoryOpts = options.map( function(category) {
            return (
                <option>{category}</option>
            );
        });

    var filteredOptions = _.filter(this.props.planOptions, {"category": this.state.selectedCategory});
        var foodOpts = filteredOptions.map( function(option) {
            return (
                <option>{option.food}</option>
            );
        });
        return (
     <tr>
             <td>{this.props.mealEntry.mealName}</td>
       <td>
             <select className="form-control" onChange={this.categoryChange}>
                 <option>Pick one... </option>
         {categoryOpts}
             </select>
       </td>

       <td>
             <select className="form-control" disabled={!this.state.selectedCategory}>
         {foodOpts}
             </select>
       </td>
     </tr>
        );
    }
});


var CategoryCounter = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h3>Counts</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
    <PlanEntryBox plan={plan} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//fb.me/react-0.13.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Meal Plan Example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="content">

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if you found it helpful?

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly straightforward use of component `state`.

You'll want to store a count of the fruits and a count of the vegetables in the parent component (`PlanEntryBox` in your case). Start by updating `PlanEntryBox.getInitialState()` to add fields for these counters.

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        plan: {}, 
        fruitCount: 0,
        vegieCount: 0
    };
},
```

Then, add functions to the `PlanEntryBox` component to handle updating the counts:

```
addFruit: function(){
    this.setState({fruitCount: this.state.fruitCount++});
},
addVegie: function(){
    this.setState({vegieCount: this.state.vegieCount++});
}
```

(You'll also likely need methods for decrementing the counts too, but I'll leave that to you.)

Then pass a reference to these methods to each `MealEntryBox` component as as props. Modify the line `PlanEntryBox`'s `render` function to:

```
<MealEntryBox mealEntry={meal} planOptions={planOpts}
    onFruit={this.addFruit} onVegie={this.addVegie}/>
```

Then make use of the `onFruit` and `onVegie` callbacks in `MealEntryBox.categoryChange`:

```
categoryChange: function(event) {
    if(event.target.value === 'fruit'){
        this.props.onFruit();
    } else {
        this.props.onVegie();
    }

    this.setState({selectedCategory: event.target.value});
},
```

(Note: Again, this is a naive implementation. You'll need to handle decrementing the value if the user de-selects the meal or changes the type from one category to the other.)

Calling `onFruit` for example, will cause the parent component to update its state (using the `setState()` call in `addFruit()`). This will cause React to render the component, and pass new props to its child elements. You can make use of this fact by passing the counts to the `CategoryCounter` component.

Modify the line where you use `CategoryCounter` in your main `render()` function in `PlanEntryBox` like so:

```
<CategoryCounter fruits={this.state.fruitCount} vegies={this.state.vegieCount} />
```

Then in the `CategoryCounter`'s render method, display those new props:

```
render: function() {
    <div>
        <h3>Counts</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Fruits: {this.props.fruits}</li>
          <li>Vegetables: {this.props.vegies}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

To summarize the strategy:

- Store the counts using `state` in the top level component
- Pass references to callback function to the child components
- Update the state in the callback methods
- Pass the current state as props to the `CategoryCounter` so it can display the counts
- Rely on React to re-render your components anytime the state changes, which will cause new props to be passed to `CategoryCounter`, which then also re-render and display its new props.

For further reading on the Callbacks and passing data **up** the component tree, see step five of the React Tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-5-add-inverse-data-flow